# Optimal way to win at Damath

Tags: damath

[image: empty board]

[image: board with chips]

As you can see, this is an example of a DaMath board with Integers.

See this [Wikipedia article about DaMath with its rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damath).

Is there any optimal way to win if you are the first or second player? Like a set of moves or strategies to keep in mind of when playing this game? Or an opening trap to score high and make your opponent get negative points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer: since Damath is a two-player game of complete information and no randomness, [Zermelo's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_(game_theory)) says that one of the following is true:

- There is a dominant strategy for 1st player.
- There is a dominant strategy for 2nd player.
- There are strategies for both players that guarantee they don't lose, i.e. perfect play results in a draw (like Tic-Tac-Toe).

As far as I can tell, no one has yet determined which of these three is true. Checkers (aka Draughts or Dama, the game Damath is based on) was ['solved' in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_(draughts_player)) with the aid of computers: two perfect players will always draw. Thus I would assume that modern computers are powerful enough to 'solve' Damath as well, but I don't know what the result would be.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to try and capture high scoring pieces on addition and multiplication squares and capture negative pieces on minus and division squares. If you are to loose a piece if it had a positive score try to make the operand division or subtraction and if you are to loose a negative piece make the operand multiplication or addition.
This would maximize your score and minimize your opponents score.